# Filing for taxes as an F-1 on Stipend

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, f1-student-visa, form-1040

I'm an F-1 Student that was on a co-op for 7 months and during this, 14% of my stipend was withheld, every month. Since this was not an employment, I will not be getting a W2, instead I'll be provided with 1042s. I will have to file a 1040 NREZ as well, but is there any possibility I would get any amount back from what was withheld? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what question you're asking, but here's a stab at an answer: *all* your withheld money will be turned over to the US federal government to cover your taxes for that year. As you fill in your [1040-NREZ](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nre.pdf), you will work out the amount of federal tax you owe for that year (line 17 on the [2016 form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040nre.pdf)): if this is *less* than the withheld amount, then the IRS will give you back the difference, and on your 1040-NREZ you can provide a bank account into which that difference will be deposited (line 23a-d) or an address to which a cheque should be mailed (line 23e). If, on the other hand, you owe *more* money than you've already paid as withheld income, you will inform the IRS how much you owe (line 21), which you can pay by [a number of ways](https://www.irs.gov/payments), including by mailing a cheque to the IRS.

Instead of filling out a 1040-NREZ yourself, I'd recommend paying for tax preparation software designed for international students to the US, such as Glacier or SprinTax -- and it's possible that your school provides free or discounted copies to their students, so check with your international office!